# Missing MongoDB database one day after importing it from a json file

Tags: mongodb

I don't know what I may be doing wrong, but all my data desappeared twice after importing from a json file.

I hosted a server on aws, installed mongo using the documentation on their site and connected using Compass, then I imported the Json file into a new database. It worked as expected, but one day after that, the database doesnt exist anymore and I have no clue why.

Is there any configuration wrong? Or am I not making the import properly?
All configuration used is default.

Comment: There is something that you are missing here, no settings should be able to do this.

Comment: Did you enable authentication on your mongodb instance?  If not, the mostly likely answer is that some script kiddie from the internet helpfully deleted all of the data before it could be compromised.  List the databases and collections to find the ransom message.

Comment: @Joe It really was! There was no important data there and I have a backup from them.
How did they do that? It might be some service I used? Was probably exposed asomeshow? I did stoped the server now until I can solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data was deleted by someone else.

There are people that randomly scan the internet looking for unsecured MongoDB servers to attack.  The usual attack simply deletes all of the data and leaves a ransom node with instructions to pay in bitcoin.

This [article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/hacker-ransoms-23k-mongodb-databases-and-threatens-to-contact-gdpr-authorities/) on ZDNet from mid 2020 describes a recent version of this attack.

The main defense against these sorts of attacks is to require a username and password to access the database.

Check out [How to Avoid a Malicious Attack That Ransoms Your Data](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data), and its [update](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/update-how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data)